# I can't get data and post it in my html

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

**model**

```
public function getPost(){
    $this->db->select('post_title', 'post_auth', 'post_content');
    $this->db->from('post');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**controller**

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('swmodel');
    $data['posts'] = $this->swmodel->getPost();
    $this->load->view('dashBoard', $data);
}
```

How can I transfer data in my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I can't say you why, but for some reason in CodeIgniter 3 you have to store the result or return of your function in a variable and then that variable assign it within the array based value you pass to your view as `$this->load->view('dashBoard', $data);`.

You need to check does exist a view called dashBoard? and where is it?

So you can try with something like:

```
public function index() {
  $this->load->model('posts_model');
  // Get your posts, store them in $posts.
  $posts = $this->posts_model->getPost();
  // Assign your $posts to your $data.
  $data['posts'] = $posts;
  // Pass your $data when you load the view.
  $this->load->view('dashBoard', $data);
}
```

And then in your view you can easily access to the passed data as `$posts`.

```
# dashBoard.php
<?php var_dump($posts); ?>
```